# SQL Query to replace characters by getting record list from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote the below query to take an id as input, get DocumentID from Attachment table and then use that id to get Document name from Document table. Once i get document name i am removing anything but the character a-z and numbers. The below Query is working fine if only one Document id is being returned based on Entity id, how can i make it work if one entity id returns more than one Document ID. I also need to return all those new names as well.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NormalizeDocumentFileName1] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id nvarchar(16),
    @temp varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

  Select @temp=Document.TheName from Document where id = (Select DocumentId from Attachment where EntityId = @id)
  Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
  Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9-_.]%'
  While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @temp) > 0
  Set @temp = Stuff(@temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @temp), 1, '')
   
END
```

Comment: That code is product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Its SQL server 2014

Comment: You would start by using joins instead of subqueries to get the document names. Then you would want to use a select statement at the end instead of an output parameter so you can get a list of names. And I would use a table valued function to remove the characters you don't want.

Comment: xpvt214o/687526/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go with a very different approach with this. I'm going to make use of Alan Burstein's [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/).

You want to avoid the `WHILE` loop, it'll perform awfully, and go with a dataset approach. I'm going to use a Function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NormalizeDocumentFileName (@FileName varchar(50) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    WITH Tokens AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.NGrams8k (@FileName,1) --If you didn't create the function on the dbo schema, you'll need to change it.
        WHERE token NOT LIKE '%[^a-z0-9-_.]%')
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),(SELECT Token + '' 
                                FROM Tokens
                                ORDER BY Position
                                FOR XML PATH(''))) AS NormalFileName;
GO
```

Then you can do something as simple as:

```
SELECT D.YourColumn, NDFN.NormalFileName
FROM Document D
     CROSS APPLY NormalizeDocumentFileName(D.TheName) NDFN;
```

Comment: It looks simple, however while creating procedure it says Invalid Object for NGrams8K,Tokens

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava Sounds like you haven't created the NGrams8K function on the database.

Comment: NGrams8K! Whoohoo! :)
@NikhilSrivastava click the link Larnu provided to get the T-SQL code to create Ngrams8k.

Comment: it works like a charm, had to change few bits here and there, but eventually its working. Thanks Larnu.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You can dispense with the `while` loop and use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      Select d.TheName, 0 as lev, d.TheName as orig_TheName
      from Document d
      where d.id = (Select DocumentId from Attachment where EntityId = @id)
      union all
      select Stuff(cte.thename, PatIndex(@KeepValues, cte.thename), 1, '') as DocumentId lev + 1, cte.orig_TheName
      from cte
      where PatIndex(@KeepValues, cte.thename) > 0
     )
select theName
from (select theName, max(lev) over (partition by orig_thename) as max_lev
      from cte
     ) x
where lev = max_lev
```

Comment: i am getting error at theName, documentid, max_lev and lev present in the bottommost select query

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava . . . I think the problem was the `documentid`.

Answer (score 0):

Another set-based function for this type of thing is [PatExclude8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/) the function does the same thing as what Larnu put together and is reusable. You would have to use the link to get the T-SQL code to create the function. The function works like this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(50) = '$$$123___!!!555.ABC???';

SELECT * FROM dbo.patexclude8k(@string, '[^A-Za-z0-9-_.]');
```

Returns:

```
NewString
------------
123___555.ABC
```

Note that what LARNU put together will return entity references for XML characters such as "&", ">", etc. But it will perform better than Patexclude. If you don't expect to deal special XML characters you can use a slightly modified version that will perform relatively the same - here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatExclude8K_NXP
(
    @String VARCHAR(8000),
    @Pattern VARCHAR(50)
) 
/*******************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a string (@String) and a pattern (@Pattern) of characters to remove, 
 remove the patterned characters from the string.

Usage:
--===== Basic Syntax Example
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.PatExclude8K_NXP(@String,@Pattern);

--===== Remove all but Alpha characters
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^A-Za-z]%');

--===== Remove all but Numeric digits
 SELECT CleanedString
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^0-9]%');

 Programmer Notes:
 1. @Pattern is case sensitive (the function can be easily modified to make it so)
 2. There is no need to include the "%" before and/or after your pattern since since we 
    are evaluating each character individually

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 20180508 Initial Development - Alan Burstein

*******************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH
E1(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) AS X(N)),
itally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP(CONVERT(INT,LEN(@String),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM E1 T1 CROSS JOIN E1 T2 CROSS JOIN E1 T3 CROSS JOIN E1 T4
) 
SELECT NewString =
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,N,1)
  FROM iTally
  WHERE 0 = PATINDEX(@Pattern,SUBSTRING(@String COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
  FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

Lastly, both NGrams8K and PatExclude perform quite a bit better when the optimizer chooses a parallel execution plan. To force a parallel plan you can use [Make_parallel](http://dataeducation.com/next-level-parallel-plan-forcing-an-alternative-to-8649/) by Adam Machanic. Using Larnu's solution as an example you would force a parallel plan like so:

```
SELECT D.YourColumn, NDFN.NormalFileName
FROM Document D
     CROSS APPLY NormalizeDocumentFileName(D.TheName) NDFN;
     CROSS APPLY dbo.make_parallel();
```

Comment: Mine shouldn't return things like `&amp;`, as the CTE will only return letters, numbers and - or _; none of which are reserved in xml. :) I agree it would, however, if I were returning other characters, but that isn't what the OP wants. Kind of fortunate in this case.

Comment: Yep - we were on the same page. My comment was intended more just to be informative for future cases.

Comment: I really like that link about`make_parallel` by the way. It kind of amuses me the odd things you can do to get the query optimiser to do what you want. Especially a query that is asking to use `TOP(9223372036854775807)`. O.o